# Pass collection to FileIO.match().filepattern()

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a list of URLs with wildcard inside of them, how can I pass it to FileIO.match().filepattern(XXXX)

here is the code

```java
PCollectionTuple decompressOut =
  pipeline
    .apply(TextIO.read("dict.txt"))
    .apply("MatchFile(s)", FileIO.match().filepattern())
    .apply(
      "DecompressFile(s)",
      ParDo.of(new Decompress(options.getOutputDirectory()))
           .withOutputTags(
               DECOMPRESS_MAIN_OUT_TAG,
               TupleTagList.of(DEADLETTER_TAG)));
```

in dict.txt I have list of URLs that I would like to pass to the XXX

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make use of matchAll to read a PCollection which contains the filenames.

From the section titled : "Example: Matching a PCollection of filepatterns arriving from Kafka" section in [Link to Beam Java doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html)

```
 PCollection<String> filepatterns = p.apply(KafkaIO.read()...);

 PCollection<Metadata> matches = filepatterns.apply(FileIO.matchAll()
     .withEmptyMatchTreatment(DISALLOW));
```

Replacing the KafkaIO.read() with TextIO.